# Using a propertyGrid in C# Winforms to store information in a grid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

Could anyone help me out on something that is confusing. I'm trying to create a grid to store information for example document details: (name, type, summary as example headers).

When the summary is too large for the cell of the grid I would like to have a button that would open a new control where the user is able to view more information.

Is it possible to to this using a propertyGrid and would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on information on doing this?

I was thinking it might be a case of writing a surrogate class and expose the objects created on it?

Thanks

Comment: Just ditch the PropertyGrid and make a proper form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is posible.

You should create your own type that will provide document details as a set of type properties. You should then attach an instance of this type to the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx). You can use attributes to change property visibility, editor, description and the others beheviours.

See [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) for further details.