# Simulate Properties Window of visual studio in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to design a panel like properties window of visual studio in my winform application.
Infact i want to have a grid that can accept a combobox as one of its cells,so user could select one of its items instead of typing.

I know it is possible in wpf but i want to know if there is any way to do this in winform app?

**Edit:**
I'm looking for a way to show the result of FooForm in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016239/how-to-create-custom-propertygrid-editor-item-which-opens-a-form) just in front of FooProperty.

**Note:** I can not place screen shot of my real application here! but i have something like the following picture in my property grid and i want to show the name of the selected Background Image as value of BackgroudImage property that specified in the red rectangle instead of (none) value.

[image]

please tell me if there is a way to do this?

Comment: what have you tried? Did you ever make a goole search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226896/using-a-propertygrid-in-c-sharp-winforms-to-store-information-in-a-grid ?

Comment: I think what you want is the `PropertyGrid` control. It will read all the properties of an object displaying and allowing user to change the properties at runtime like as you do with `Properties Window` at design time.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was placed "on hold" - the question is entirely self-explanatory and fully contained, IMO. It certainly is not "off-topic", which was the selected reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grid can be provided via `PropertyGrid`; this uses the `System.ComponentModel` implementation, which is very flexible but quite complex. However, to provide suggested values - you use the `GetStandardValues` method of `TypeConverter`. Full example:

(**edit**: needs `CanConvertFrom` / `ConvertFrom` to work as combo)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public class MyType
    {
        [TypeConverter(typeof(GiveMeOptionsConverter))]
        public string SomeProperty {get;set;}


        private class GiveMeOptionsConverter : TypeConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
            {
                return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
            }
            public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
            {
                if (value is string) return value;
                return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
            }
            public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            {
                return true;
            }
            public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            {
                return false; // true is drop-down; false is combo
            }
            public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            {
                // this gives you the `MyType` instance if you need it
                var obj = (MyType)context.Instance;

                return new StandardValuesCollection(
                    new[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" });
            }
        }
    }
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            using (var grid = new PropertyGrid {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                SelectedObject = new MyType()
            })
            using (var form = new Form { Controls = { grid } })
            {
                Application.Run(form);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, That was worked well.But now i have another question; How can i add something like "Items" property of ComboBox control to my propertygrid? I mean i want to have a textbox with a browse button next to it as a property of propertygrid, that a form opens when the button will be clicked.

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi that would require a custom `UITypeEditor` implementation associated via `[TypeEditor(...)]`, with `GetEditStyle()` returning `UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal`

Comment: Thanks again,I have tried your solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016239/how-to-create-custom-propertygrid-editor-item-which-opens-a-form  , But the problem is that i do not want to have expandableObject.Infact i want to show the result of FooForm just in front of FooProperty not as the value of Bar property.

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi you don't need to use expandable object converter at all; the type-editor is entirely separate

Comment: But i could not show the result of FooForm as the value of FooProperty! I'm looking for a way to do this! (Note : I am too new with TypeEditor)

Comment: OK Marc, may i ask another question? How can i set the value of a combo griditem? I do NOT mean the default value! but also i mean the value that was selected in previous time.

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi sorry, can you rephrase that? I couldn't follow exactly what you were trying to do. Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: Your welcome Marc,I have found the solution of my last question but i have my Penultimate question yet.I have updated my question.

Comment: My question has been answered in http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/661406/Problem-with-propertygrid?cmt=520428#cmt2_661406 by johannesnestler.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) control. You'll find plenty of examples on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PropertyGrid and a custom type editor for doing that.

Here you have a detailed explanation of what you can do with a property grid, and how do a custom UI type editor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

Comment: Actually, a custom type editor (`UITypeEditor` etc) won't directly help with this... this is done in `TypeConverter`